# Generic grade system

Tags: c#, oop, generics

In  my   project  I need some  functionality similar to  student **grade system** where  using  ***generics***  is  must.User may enter the  data or we could fetch the  data's  from DB but  demo  basic   functionality  will be  like  this below

```
 class Student
   {
      private string _name;
      private double _grade;


      public string Name
      {
         get { return _name; }
         set { _name = value; }
      }

      public double Grade
      {
         get { return _grade; }
         set { _grade = value; }
      }


      public Student(string name, double grade)
      {
         this.Name = name;
         this.Grade = grade;
      }
   }



      class Students: List<Student>
       {
          public void Print()
          {
             Console.WriteLine("Student\t\tGrade");
             Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
              foreach (Student student in this)
              {
                if (student != null)
                {
                   Console.WriteLine(student.Name + "\t\t" + student.Grade);
                }
             }
          }
       }




     class Program
       {
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {
             Students students = new Students();

         //add the student to the list
         students.Add(new Student("Tom", 83));
         students.Add(new Student("Joe", 86));
         students.Add(new Student("Rudy", 85));
         students.Add(new Student("Chris", 87));
         students.Add(new Student("Keith", 85));
         students.Add(new Student("Pepe", 75));
         students.Add(new Student("Juan", 88.9));
         students.Add(new Student("Pedro", 75));
         students.Add(new Student("Pablo", 75));
         students.Add(new Student("Jose", 79));
         students.Add(new Student("Tommy", 88));

         //implement our custom comparer for grades
         //students.Sort(new StudentGradeComparer());


         students.Print();
         Console.ReadLine();
      }
   }
```

But  later  some  functionality  added  like I have to  print A,B,C,F only not the marks like 88 or 76 . It'll  be  like this  below ,

```
if (marks >= 80) 
      grade = 'A';
   else if (marks >= 70) 
      grade = 'B';
   else if (marks >= 60)
      grade = 'C';
   else if (marks >= 50)
      grade = 'D';
   else if (marks >= 40)
      grade = 'E';
   else
      grade = 'U'; // unclassified
```

but within that  i enumerable and  generic  list  I am  having  difficulties , please  help  me  on this.using generics my 1st piece of code works fine and printing tom 88 joe 77 etc but I need Tom A joe B with the formula described by 2nd piece of code. So my difficulty here is to merge this 2 piece of code. Thanks.

Comment: `I am having difficulties` Well, describe the difficulties. Don't assume we know what your problem is.

Comment: This above  code  will print   tom  88    then  joe  77  etc

But  intead  of  that  I need  Tom  A   JOe  B

Comment: Why is using generics a must?

Comment: You have not shown the code that actually returns the grade. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: To be   fit in  larger  ways  beacuse  there  is   some  other  functionality  and this   is  just small  part  of  that....that's why  generics  is must

Comment: @mason Yes he did... `Console.WriteLine(student.Name + "\t\t" + student.Grade);`

Comment: @mason  I need  that  code   which'll  return/print  grade like  A,B  not  88,56  etc  which  is  returning  now within  this  functionality  that's why  I  asked  this  q

Comment: @AndrewArnold No, he did not. His second set of code isn't shown in context with the first. The problem likely is there, but it's hard to say because it's not shown.

Comment: @UserCSharp Yes, I understand that and I'm trying to help you. But realize I'm not magic, you must provide an example like the one I described in the link so that we are able to help you. You are clearly missing some code.

Comment: 2nd  set of   code  is  the   required  code  which must   be   somehow  added  to the  above  class.  THat's  why I added  the  2nd   piece of  code.  That  piece  is  not  within  any  class/methods....but  I  want  that  2nd piece  of  code  within  my 1st piece  to  do that  am  facing  difficulties.

Comment: How are generics supposed to fit into this? Other than the generic list, I don't see what's supposed to be generic here

Comment: @matt  To be fit in larger ways beacuse there is some other functionality and this is just small part of that....that's why generics is must.  using generics  my  1st  piece  of  code  works  fine  and  printing  tom 88  joe  77   etc  but   I need   Tom A  joe B   with  the  formula   described  by  2nd  piece  of  code.

So  my  difficulty  here  is  to  merge  this  2  piece  of  code

Comment: @UserCSharp: You keep saying that, but it doesn't make sense. What needs to be "generic" here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's more than one way to do this, but I'd probably do something like add a function `LetterGradeFromNumber` to your `Students` class (an alternative would be to have a property in your `Student` class that will return the letter grade):

```
private string LetterGradeFromNumber(int marks)
{
    if (marks >= 80) 
      return 'A';
    else if (marks >= 70) 
      return 'B';
    else if (marks >= 60)
      return 'C';
    else if (marks >= 50)
      return 'D';
    else if (marks >= 40)
      return 'E';
    else
      return 'U'; // unclassified
    }
}
```

Then change `Print` to take an argument to switch between numeric and letter grades (or you can make a separate function if you want):

```
  public void Print(bool letterGrades = false)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("Student\t\tGrade");
     Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
     foreach (Student student in this)
     {
        if (student != null)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(student.Name + "\t\t" + letterGrades? LetterGradeFromNumber(student.Grade) : student.Grade.ToString());
        }
      }
  }
```

Comment: +1 for the clean answer (though I would have done it as a property)

Comment: @mason: I'd lean towards a property too unless there is a need to be able to map grades differently under different circumstances.

Comment: Depending on where your program goes, that conditional tree might be better off in its own Grade class, with toNumber() and toLetter() methods on it.

Comment: @jrahhali: Not an unreasonable suggestion, but I don't know how `toNumber` would work. If you pass it a letter grade, you won't be able to get back the original numeric grade because, for example, an `A` is anything over 80.

Comment: Make Grade an immutable value object: Grade grade = new Grade(88);  grade.toLetter() returns 'A', grade.toNumber() returns 88.

Answer (score 2):

First off, I don't see why generics are a must here or really how they even fit in. Why can't you add the numerical grade to letter grade conversion method or a property to your `Student` class? It would look like:

```
public class Student
{
    public string LetterGrade {
        get {
            if (Grade >= 80)
                return "A";
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Or:

```
public class Student
{
    public string GetLetterGrade() {
        if (Grade >= 80)
            return "A";
        ...
    }
}
```

But if you absolutely have to use a generic *something* you can do the following:

```
public class LetterGradeCalculator<T> where T : ILetterGradeFactory, new()
{
    private readonly ILetterGradeFactory _factory;

    public GradeCalculator() {
        _factory = new T();
    }

    public string GetLetterGrade(int numericalGrade) {
        return _factory.CreateLetterGrade(numericalGrade);
    }
}

public interface ILetterGradeFactory
{
    string GetLetterGrade(int numericalGrade);
}

public class SixPointLetterGradeCalculator : ILetterGradeFactory
{
    public string GetLetterGrade(int numericalGrade) {
        if (numericalGrade >= 94)
            return "A";
        ...
    }
}
```

At least now `LetterGradeCalculator` is generic... And then use it in place of the `LetterGrade` property I wrote about earlier. Even if I went this route I still wouldn't make `LetterGradeCalculator` generic; I'd set it up for constructor D.I. instead. I really think this just over complicates the solution but at least you can easily create different implementations.